# Execute code when clicking on a html element without redirecting or reloading page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

So I am working on a webshop where the user should be able to add a product to the shopping cart by clicking an icon. The problem being is how would I add the selected product to the database (I am using EFCore). Also, as said in the title, I do no want the page to get reloaded or anything similar.

#### What I tried so far:

Calling an HttpPost request which would reload the page since I am returning the same View as I am already in.

Comment: I'd say that you need to use JS if you don't want to reload it.

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete So you mean I should call the HttpPost Request in the background with js?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that's what you need to do. Personally, I have worked with ASP.NET and MVC and in both cases if you needed to retain the same page, you need to use JS either by jQuery, pure or other framework.

Comment: You can use AJAX to asynchronously post your data to server. For that you need to create an API endpoint in the backend (asp. Net core). Please share which client side technology you are using i.e. Plain JavaScript or JQuery or AngularJS or Angular etc

Comment: @PrateekKumarDalbehera I mostly use JQuery

Comment: @Prateek - this is the correct answer

Comment: @Fleshy, I have added code snippet in the Answer section, please vote it if it worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find the code snippet (JS & C#) below. Please modify it as per your requirement & mention in the comments box if you faced any issue.. Thanks.

```
let _data = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'product name',
    count: 4
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "shoppingcart/add", // "{Controller}/{ActionMethod}". If in same controller, then just use the action method name.
    data: _data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) { 
        console.log(response); // In real time, read response object & use as required.
    },
    error: function (err) {
        handleError(err);
    }
});

function handleError(err) {
    console.log(`Sorry, an error occurred, details: ${err.error}`);
}

/* C# Controller */

[Route("api/shoppingcart")]
[ApiController]
public class ShoppingCart : ControllerBase
{

    [Route("add")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddProduct(Product product)
    {
        return Ok(product);
    }
}

/* C# model */
public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:
1) Send either a GET or POST request(depending on your needs) to the relevant action/controller in your ASP.NET application by using AJAX.
2) Make sure the action method returns whatever you need to change on the page - most of the times I either return a partial view or a json.
3) In the callback of the AJAX request that you sent, use the json/partial view(html) that was returned to you in the response by your action method to alter the DOM of the page as you need. 
Note: The reason you are returning a partial view and not a regular view is to omit the _layout in the HTML that you receive.

Answer (score 0):

I might need more information to be able to help. If you are using ef migrations and have a Model already, called Product for example, but note a database, do the following steps:

1. Add Data Annotations onto your model. E.g. [Key] for the ProductID, [Display(Name = "Enter Product Code")] for Product Code, etc.
2. You need to have a DbContext added. If not, then you need to choose a database, SQLite or SQL Server, add the database connection. The following two lines will generate the table using the Terminal if you are using VSCode.

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreated --output-dir Migrations --context YourDbContext
dotnet ef database update --context YourDbContext
```

3. Then you need to create a ProductsController and Views (Create and Index)
   The simplest way to generate your controller and views automatically is by installing the dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator. use this command to install it: `dotnet tool install dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator`

Now make sure the following lines are added to your csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>  
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />  
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />  
  </ItemGroup>
```

3. run the aspnet-codegenerator

```
dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name ProductsController -m Product -dc YourDbContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries
```

4. Go to the ProductsController and look for the following code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
```

5. To call the Create.cshtml from anywhere should look somthing like this:

```
<a asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Products" method="post" >Create New</a>
```

Note! Products does not have the workd Controller after it.

Below is an example of the Create.cshtml web page

```
@model test_mvc_webapp.Models.Product

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Product</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProductCode" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProductCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductCode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProductType" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="ProductType" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Let me know if this helped?